# Probability problem regarding distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

Here which distribution should I use? I am confused between hypergeometric and multinomial distributions

Comment: Definitely hypergeometric. Each candy picked is reducing the total number of candies left in the packet.

Comment: @Tavish then delete your initial comment so it does not confuse future readers who might just take the first response they see and assume that it is correct.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sure. tommik should delete his comment as well.

Comment: @ Novice, it is worth pointing out that it is technically an assumption (*though a very safe assumption*) that we select without replacement here... (*after all, once you eat a candy, it has already been consumed.  If we wanted 50 pieces of candy to eat, after we eat one we hope to still have 49 candies remaining*).  It is also worth pointing out that at times if the population we are selecting from is "*LARGE*" then even though we might be selecting without replacement we simplify matters by doing the math as though we selected with replacement as it is a plenty good approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obvioulsly it is an Hypergeometric

$$\frac{\binom{100}{15}\binom{80}{35}}{\binom{180}{50}}$$

If you have time to lose you can calculate it manually....

$$\frac{\underbrace{100\times99\times\dots\times86}_{\text{15 times}}\cdot\underbrace{80\times79\times\dots\times46}_{\text{35 times}}}{\underbrace{180\times179\times\dots\times131}_{\text{50 times}}}\cdot\frac{\underbrace{50\times49\times\dots\times36}_{\text{15 times}}}{15!}$$

Comment: yeah I tried doing that but no answer came. My calculator could not give an answer

Comment: @Novice : you can leave the solution as indicated, it is not important to get a number. Anyway the numerical result is $\approx 1.4\cdot10^{-5}$, very close to zero

Comment: @Novice : see my edits for a manual calculation

Answer (score 1):

The multinomial is for an independent *series* of experiments that all have the same finitely many outcomes, and we want to count the number of experiments with cretain outcomes.

The hypergeometric is exactly for what you problem states: one *selection without replacement* from a finite number of options, that are divided into subclasses.

You can also just use combinatorial reasoning: there is a total number of $\binom{180}{50}$ draws that are possible from $180$ pieces of candy when we pick $50$ of them at once. ("all outcomes")

There are $\binom{100}{15}\binom{80}{35}$ ways to pick both $15$ from the hundred orange-flavoured ones and $35$ from the eighty strawberry-flavoured ones. (the "good" outcomes).

Their quotient will be the desired probability.

Comment: yeah I tried doing that but no answer came. My calculator could not give an answer

Comment: @Novice then get a better calculator?

Comment: @Novice or better yet... don't bother trying to get a numerical result if it wasn't asked for in the first place.  Seeing an answer written in terms of binomial coefficients is often preferred by teachers as it is clear what logic led to the answer.